# How to use Minion Task Migrations for Database Migrations

Tags: database, kohana, kohana-3, database-migration

I am running Kohana 3.3 and wanting to add database migrations to my project.

I have added the following moulde https://github.com/kohana-minion/tasks-migrations but not sure how to get it working.

I can see the help file running `./minion migrations:new --help` but I don't understand what `group` value is required. From the docs it says:

```
--group=group_name

 This is a required config option, use it specify in which group the
 migration should be stored. Migrations are stored in a `migrations`
 directory followed by the group name specified. By default, the `migrations`
 directory is created in `APPPATH` but that can be changed with `--location`

--location=modules/auth

 Specified the path of the migration (without the `migrations` directory).
 This value is defaulted to `APPPATH`

 # The migration will be created in `modules/myapp/migrations/myapp/`
 --group=myapp --location=modules/myapp

--description="Description of migration here"

 This is an arbitrary description of the migration, used to build the
 filename.  It is required but can be changed manually later on without
 affecting the integrity of the migration.
```

I've been searching for examples but yet to find one. I have an existing database, so I would like to grab the schema from that as my base and then run further migrations after. Is this how `tasks-migrations` module works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group method is used to tell you what kind of migrations it are. If it are migrations of your core application then the group `core` would be suitable.

But maybe you build yourself a module for your application that had it's own tables and thus its own migrations. thus it would be better to use the group `module_name`.

This way you can split your migrations in more suitable parts and are able to easily check only the migrations of your modules without having to search through all other migrations.

Make new migrations

```
./minion migrations:new --group=core
```

Run migrations

```
./minion migrations:run
```

PS: Dont forget to add the migrations table to the database

Comment: Thanks, btw, it created the migrations table when running the first migration.

Comment: BTW make sure when it creates the table that when you are using innodb you also change it to innodb. Mixed table types can cause database backup problems if you are using fast copy methods.

Answer (score 0):

The group was the migration version number e.g.

`./minion migrations:new --group=0-1`

Created a folder and migration file in application/migrations/0.1 with the up and down methods.